# Эффект нажатия на drawableRight в EditText

Tags: java, android

Есть `EditText`, у него установлен `drawableRight`, но когда по нему нажимаешь  - нет никакого отображения действия, т.е. не понятно, нажал я или нет.

Как можно установить эффект нажатия?

Обычно устанавливал при помощи:

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

.

```
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="248dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    android:hint="@string/search_query_hint" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае вы работаете не с бэкграундом всего виджета, а с отдельным изображением на виджете, поэтому назначать реакцию клика на бэкграунд неправильно.

Для того, чтобы был эффект нажатия у изображения, нужно, во первых, подготовить изображения для каждого состояния. Например, вид нажатого состояния `ic_search_black_pressed.png` и дефолтного (нормального)  `ic_search_black.png`.
Затем нужно написать селектор, который будет реагировать на каждое состояние, назовем его `search_black_selector.xml` (размещаем в папке *res/drawable/*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/ic_search_black_pressed.png" /> <!-- изображение для нажатого состояния -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_search_black" /> <!-- изображение нормального состояния -->
</selector>
```

Теперь подключаем этот селектор в `EditText` вместо статичной картинки:

```
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="248dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/search_black_selector" />
```

Так же возможны реакции на другие состояния виджетов и их комбинации - [официальный гайд по вопросу](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)